# Can't run some TFS commands

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to change the owner of a TFS Project Collection with [this command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workspace-command):

```
tf workspaces /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs/applications applications;OLD.OWNER /newowner:NEW.OWNER
```

But I am getting this error:

> Unrecognized command option 'newowner`

---

I also tried with `workspace` instead of `workspaces` as suggested by Giulio, but with this error:

> The workspace applications;OLD.OWNER does not exist. Please specify an existing workspace or /new to create one.

---

Also tried adding a `/computer:COMPUTERNAME` switch, but this gives the same error as the previous attempt.

---

Interestingly, when I try querying all workspaces with

```
tf workspaces /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs
```

I get:

> Unable to retrieve the registration information for 'ISCCProvider'

And the same error is produced if I specify the `computer`

---

I am running this command from the `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015`, but not on the TFS server itself (I am running it from my machine).

I am the owner of all project collections.

I am able to call `tf workspaces` without any issue, and I can also call `tf workspaces /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs/applications`  with the expected results.

What could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean about change the owner for project collection? There is no owner for a project collection in TFS.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Hi Eddie, I think what I mean to say is to change the owner of a workspace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you typing

```
tf workspaces /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs
```

You will  definitely get this error

> Unable to retrieve the registration information for 'ISCCProvider'

Since this command `tf workspaces` it's collection level not server level, your address (`http://appdev:8080/tfs`) is server url, you just need to add your collection info of the url such as `http://appdev:8080/tfs/applications`  The error will disappear.

---

In your case :

1. **First** typing

   `tf workspaces /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs/applications`

   This will **list all workspaces belongs to you** on your computer.
2. **Then** typing

   `tf workspace/collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs/applications workspacename/newowner:xxx`

   The *workspace* name is the one which you want to change the owner.
   You can get the info from the first command.  You don't have to add
   the **older owner name** and option, just need to add new owner
   name.
3. **Finally** you cloud also typing

   `tf workspaces /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs/applications`

   again, you will see
   the changed workspace **will not list any more**.  This is make
   sense, since the owner is changed and the workspace not longer
   belongs to you.

Answer (score 2):

Mind the spelling: you want `tf workspace` but you typed `tf workspaces` which is a different command.

Comment: Hi Giulio thanks for your comment. I tried that but the system complains that the workspace does not exist. To be clear, `Applications` in my environment is a `Project Collection` - does what I am trying to do even make sense?

Comment: have you specified the `/computer` option? a workspace is tied to a machine

Comment: That seems to give the same error (see my updated question). Is it possible that I am missing a dependency or some installation or similar?

Comment: You must specify the path to the collection e.g. `http://appdev:8080/tfs/mycollection`

Answer (score 1):

`tf workspace` and `tf workspaces` command is used to set/configure the workspaces, and the command used to change the owner of the workspace is:

```
tf workspace /collection:http://appdev:8080/tfs/collectionname workspacename;oldowner /newowner:newowner
```

You cannot use this command to change the settings for project collection.